# Github search for matches in different filenames

Tags: github

I use `Github` search engine pretty often to see how other users have used some function.

The problem is that there is a bunch of repeated results due to copied repositories. Is there any way to search for a text but show only the matches in files with different name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Return repositories not including forks]

I believe this is what you're looking for.  First, search for something.  Select "Code" from the menu on the left, and at the bottom you'll see Advanced Search.  Find this option and change whatever you like.

Comment: Hi, you are right that works for forked repos but a lot of people just copy them so they are not forked. Is there a way to search by unique file names? Thanks

Comment: @user1618465 It sounds like you're trying to solve a difficult problem because you're searching for a file that has been copied many times, but you still want a specific version?  Could you clarify what exactly you're trying to search for, and maybe I can help you with that

Comment: I just don't want to show matches of files with the same name. So if I'm looking for the string `foo` and there is two files with the same name `common_name.txt` I just want to show one of them. Thanks